# if a value is on mysqli database do not create a button on php

Tags: php, mysqli, foreach, while-loop

I have a database table like

```
-----------------
| id | time     |
|----|----------|
| 1  | 9am-10am |
| 2  | 11am-12pm|
```

and a PHP array

```
$times= array("8am-9am","9am-10am","10am-11am","11am-12pm","12pm-1pm","1pm-2pm","2pm-3pm","3pm-4pm","4pm-5pm","5pm-6pm","6pm-7pm","7pm-8pm","8pm-9pm","9pm-10pm");
```

My problem is, if the time is already in the database, the code shouldn't create a button with that value so I have the following foreach loop

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `time_table`";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
foreach($times as $value){
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        if($value!=$row['time']){
            echo "<button>$value</button>";
        }
    }
}
```

But instead of showing all other values not 9am-10am and 11am-12pm instead it just shows two 8am-9am button

Comment: I don't understand what do you expect as result ? What is `$value` ?

Comment: you are only running through the mysqli_resultset once, on the first instance of your foreach. you need to rethink your logic. fetch the mysql result outside your foreach, put the results in an array, and then use that array in a foreach instead of your while loop

Comment: are u looking for in_array() ?

Comment: it should output all button not 9am-10am and 11am-12pm, so for above it should show a 8am-9am,10am-11am,12pm-1pm....... buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your code to this:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `time_table`";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
 foreach($times as $value){
  mysqli_data_seek($result,0); //reset the pointer to search from the first row every time
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
   if($value==$row['time']){
    continue 2; //exits while loop and then skips foreach to the next $value
   }
  }
  echo "<button>$value</button>";
 }
```

Or the other solution (based on the other answer, so credits to `JoSSte`, but slightly modified, so it wouldn't have to iterate through the array):

```
$savedValues = array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `time_table`";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
 $savedValues[$row['time']] = 1;
}

foreach($times as $value){
 if(!isset($savedValues[$value])){ 
  echo "<button>$value</button>";
 }
}
```

Comment: There's a problem, you should fetch all the results before loop through the array, otherwise nothing is fetched since the second loop.

Answer (score 2):

It should work if you use `in_array()` and separate the loops, that way it will get more readable.

```php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `time_table`";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$resultTimes = array();

// Assign the DB values to an array
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $resultTimes[] = $row['time'];
}

// Check if values from $times are in the array, if not echo button
foreach ($times as $value) {
  if (!in_array($value, $resultTimes)) {
    echo "<button>$value</button>";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are only running through the `mysqli_resultset` once, on the first instance of your `foreach`.

You need to rethink your logic. Fetch the mysql result outside your `foreach`, put the results in an array, and then use that array in a foreach instead of your while loop.

```
//first, fetch the rows from DB
$savedValues = array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `time_table`";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $savedValues[]  = $row['time'];
}

//then compare
foreach($times as $value){ 
  foreach($savedValues as $svd){
   if($svd != $value){
     echo "<button>$value</button>";
   }
  }
 }
```

**NOTE:** this is not optimal. as another comment states, you should consider `in_array()` or something similar to avoid loops in loops

Comment: Would use `$savedValues[$row['time']] = 1;` and then just `if(!isset($savedValues[$value])){}` - the most effective way

Comment: i like that approach @FlashThunder